# Library to compress arbitrary data structures in Python

Tags: python, compression, lzw

I have an application written in Python that stores many lists of basic datatypes (int, floats etc) which are in turn rarely accessed. I was looking at some libraries that could compress this data before further processing.

I looked at [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) and other similar libraries. It seems to me that they all work on strings. Why is that? Is there any limitation at applying LZ77 to a list of int rather than a list of chars?

Is there a python library out there that will do what I want?

Comment: well you could compress the ints to chars(perhaps with `struct.pack`... then gzip the chars or something

Comment: That should work but I was wondering if there is a more fundamental reason why they only compress strings. Moreover if I use struct.pack will it be as efficient as compressing the raw binary data?

Comment: the raw binary data is likely what struct pack would generate ... the raw binary data is what you should gzip

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to serialize the Python object(s) using [pickle or cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which will convert it to a series of bytes.  Then you can use any compressor, such as [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html), to compress it.  Then you can use zlib and pickle to turn the data back into objects.  Both pickle and zlib can work solely in memory.

Answer (score 0):

if you have python 3.4, you can do this with the [lzma library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html).

If you are in python 2.7 you can use the [bz2](http://pymotw.com/2/bz2/) library to compress data in memory.

The examples in the links look pretty good so I won't re-write them here.

Comment: I want to compress data in memory.

Comment: It still requires data to be in str format..